# Axon framework: No qualifying bean of type EventScheduler

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, axon

So I tried to autowired EventScheduler in my saga class like this.

```
@Saga
class ConfirmRegistrationSaga {
  @Autowired
  @Transient
  private lateinit var eventScheduler: EventScheduler
  ...
}
```

but it gives me this error

```
No qualifying bean of type 'org.axonframework.eventhandling.scheduling.EventScheduler' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

what's going on here? do I need to config something to use evenScheduler? I use axon-spring-boot-starter version 4.1.2 and spring-boot version 2.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe you have to configure the `EventScheduler` Bean yourself if you are not using `AxonServer`.
Try adding this to your `@Configuration`, for example:

```
@Bean
public SimpleEventSchedulerFactoryBean simpleEventSchedulerFactoryBean() {
  return new SimpleEventSchedulerFactoryBean();
}
```

Just adding that Axon provides different implementations for the `EventScheduler` as you can see [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/deadlines/event-schedulers#scheduled-events-as-deadlines).